# Possible Staircases using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

For the Staircase problem mentioned in the URL http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?num=1017&locale=en
[image]

Can we solve it in linear time O(k) where k is the maximum steps possible? I felt like missing some logic using below approach

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Below is the code That I have implemented:

```
    def answer(n):
        steps = determine_steps(n)
        x = ((n -1) - n/steps) * ((n-2) - n/steps + 1)  #Minimum of two stair case
        for i in range(3, steps):
            x = x * ((n-i)/i)    #Stairs from 3 can go from minimum height 0 to max (n-i)/i
        return x


    def determine_steps(n):
        """Determine no of steps possible"""
        steps = 1;
        while (steps * steps + steps) <= 2 * n:
            steps = steps + 1
        return steps - 1

    #print answer(212)
    print answer(212)
```

Comment: What is `k`? I cannot see it in the link. Also can you explain the approach you mention?

Comment: K = for a given n bricks maximum no of steps possible.

Comment: ...yeah I can read that in your question, what about the approach you are mentioning? :))

Comment: For Example, consider the left most step which cannot go below n/k and  cannot have height more than n-1. So for each step, we calculate the possible height it can grow from it possible minimum height.

Comment: The question is more likely to stay open if you include the original question's text rather than a link (which could later break), as well as include some details about the approach you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: It can be solved in O(n^3) which fits nicely in the time and memory limits.

Comment: As you can see in this answer to your example of N = 212, I believe the answer is equivalent to the number of distinct partitions of N subtracted by 1 for the partition [N]; wolfram link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+distinct+partitions+of+212&x=0&y=0 There are various methods for this - I like the recurrence described in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts

Answer (score 4):

Suppose, you have a function which takes 2 parameters, one `left` which is number of bricks left and the other one is `curr` which is the current height of the step which you are on. Now, at any step you have 2 options. The first option is to increase the height of the current step you are on by adding one more brick, i.e., `rec(left-1, curr+1)` and the second option is to create a new step whose height should be greater than `curr` ,i.e., `rec(left-curr-1, curr+1)` ( you created a step of height `curr+1` ). Now, `left` can never be negative , thus `if left<0 then return 0`. And when `left` is 0 that means, we have created a valid staircase,thus `if left==0 then return 1`.

This case: `if dp[left][curr] !=-1` is just for memoization.

Now, `rec( 212-1, 1 )` means a step of height 1 is created and it is the current step. And for final answer `1` is subtracted because any valid staircase should contain at least 2 steps so, subtracting 1 for single step staircase.

```
# your code goes here
dp = [ [-1]*501 for i in range(501) ]

def rec(left, curr):
    if left<0:
        return 0
    if left==0:
        return 1
    if dp[left][curr] !=-1:
        return dp[left][curr]
    dp[left][curr] = rec(left-1, curr+1) + rec( left-curr-1, curr+1)
    return dp[left][curr]

print ( rec(212-1,1) - 1 )
```

Feel free to comment back, if you are not able to understand the code.